# How to convert a string to binary utf-16 and Binary to String in java?

Tags: java, utf-16, string-decoding

my project requires converting Arabic text to binary , then convert  binary to text (reverse process).
I used this code,but I notice that when I use utf-16 to convert string to binary, then read this binary to convert it back to the original UTF-16 String will give me different chars

for example : the Arabic char used in encoding is (ن) which converted in binary (0100011000000110) by utf-16lE

now when I want to convert these binary bits(0100011000000110) to original utf-16 string will give me different character is F.

These problem just appears if the string is Arabic characters and utf-16 encoding. How I can solve this problem..?

```
// Convert the text to binary
public static String getBinaryFromText(String secretText) {
    byte[] bytes = secretText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
    StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        int val = b;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            val <<= 1;
        }
    }

    return binary.toString();
}

// Convert the binary to text.
public static String getTextFromBinary(String binaryString) {
    String binary = binaryString.replace(" ", "");
    String binaryPer8Bits;
    byte[] byteData;
    byteData = new byte[binary.length() / 8];

    for (int i = 0; i < binary.length() / 8; i++) {
        // To divide the string into 8 characters
        binaryPer8Bits = binary.substring(i * 8, (i + 1) * 8);
        // The integer of decimal string of binary numbers
        Integer integer = Integer.parseInt(binaryPer8Bits, 2);
        // The casting to a byte type variable
        byteData[i] = integer.byteValue();
    }

    return new String(byteData);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With `new String(byteData);` you interpret the create `byte[]` with default encoding. To interpret it as UTF_16LE you need to use a different constructor:

`new String(byteData, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);`

(Almost) never use the `new String(byte[])` it will use the default encoding, so your application will be platform dependend.

Comment: I added some more explanation. Maybe you can be more specific about what you dont understand.